# Uploading Multiple file using fileReader in lwc

Tags: javascript, salesforcedx, files, fileupload

I am trying to upload multiple files using `lightning-input type="file"` below is the code.

**HTML**

```
 <lightning-input type="file" onchange={handleOnFileUpload} name="uploadFile" multiple label="Attachment">
              </lightning-input>
```

**JS**

```
@track fileData;
    @track attachmentArray = [];
    handleOnFileUpload(event) {
        console.log('event.target.files -->' + event.target.files);
        console.log("handleOnFileUpload response-->" + JSON.stringify(event.target.files));
        var response = event.target.files;
        this.attachmentArray = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
            // alert('i -->' + i);
            const fileName = response[i].name;
            console.log('fileName --->' + fileName);
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                // The file's text will be printed here
                // console.log(e.target.result);
                var base64 = e.target.result;
                // console.log('i -->' + i);
                // console.log('base64 -->' + i + base64);
                this.fileData = {
                    'filename': fileName,
                    'base64': base64
                }
                console.log(this.fileData);
                this.attachmentArray.push(this.fileData);
                console.log(this.attachmentArray); 

                alert('fffffff');
                 
            };
            reader.readAsText(response[i]);
        }

                    uploadAttachment({
                     recId: this.recordId,
                     strBase64Array: this.attachmentArray
                 }).then((result) => {
                     if (result) {
                         this.dispatchEvent(
                             new ShowToastEvent({
                                 title: "Success",
                                 message: "Attachment uploaded Successfully",
                                 variant: "Success",
                             })
                         );
                     } else {
                         this.dispatchEvent(
                             new ShowToastEvent({
                                 title: "Error",
                                 message: "Failed to Upload Attachment1",
                                 variant: "error",
                             })
                         );
                     }
                 }).catch((error) => {
                     this.dispatchEvent(
                         new ShowToastEvent({
                             title: "Error",
                             message: "Failed to Upload Attachment2",
                             variant: "error",
                         })
                     );
                 });


         
    }
```

In the console it print up to this line `console.log(this.fileData);` after that it's not executing also no error occurred in the console.

Can any one help me what I am missing in the above code. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Use Screen Flow with File Upload component, simple and easy to customize.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reading a file is asynchronous. This means that the upload code will happen **before** the files are read, and there won't be any files to read, so nothing happens. Instead, you need to wait for the files. I'd use a method to read the files that is asynchronous:

```
  readFile(fileSource) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const fileReader = new FileReader();
      const fileName = fileSource.name;
      fileReader.onerror = () => reject(fileReader.error);
      fileReader.onload = () => resolve({ fileName, base64: fileReader.result.split(',')[1]});
      fileReader.readAsDataURL(fileSource);
    });
  }
```

And you can then read all the files at once:

```
  async handleFileChange(event) {
    this.textFiles = await Promise.all(
      [...event.target.files].map(file => this.readFile(file))
    );
    // Here, you can now upload the files to the server //
  }
```

Once this loop completes, you'll have the completed file array and can do the upload.

---

Edit: I've created an [example script](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/ZHI4uqDx6dpz3sNjYTBl/src/app.js) for this question.

In this example, I use readAsDataURL to get the base64-encoded version instead, and I cleaned up the code a bit. However, it is functionally what I was trying to demonstrate.

Comment: `readFile` function should call `onchange` in HTML?

Comment: @SFDC_Beginner No, it's a helper method. You would call it from where your code is now. (handleOnFileUpload).

Comment: You mean to say that we have to pass `event.target.files` to `readFile`  from `handleOnFileUpload` function right?

Comment: @SFDC_Beginner No, you're iterating over the files, and calling an async function for each file.

Comment: Okay, But in `readFile` function expecting the `fileSource` as parameter, but this parameter value is not used in helper method.

Comment: @SFDC_Beginner I forgot a line of code, is all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119285/discussion-between-sfdc-beginner-and-sfdcfox).